# Unable to connect to Raspberry Pi 3 Model B even after enabling SSH

Tags: ssh, putty

I just got my Raspberry Pi 3 Model B today and after installing the OS image onto the microSD card along with the blank `ssh` file in the boot directory, I turned on my Pi and the OS seemed to be loaded successfully and showed up on my router (it was connected to my router since I was doing headless configuration). But when I tried to connect to the Pi using PuTTY, it says `Network Error: Connection refused`. How do I solve the problem? The SSH was enabled as prescribed by placing a blank `ssh` file so how do I solve this?

Comment: "*the blank `ssh` file in the boot directory*" -- please explain, where exactly was the "*boot directory*"

Comment: @techraf it is where the os files were located.

Comment: And you think anyone will help you, when you yourself don't care?

Comment: @techraf ok, let me explain this, once i downloded the img file from the website, i created a blank ssh file and copied it into the zip file. then used etcher and flashed it onto the sd card.

Comment: "*copied into the zip file*"? This makes no sense.

Comment: @techraf yes, but i was able to copy

Comment: @techraf oh wait sorry, it was the unzipped folder, lol

Comment: Are you using noobs?

Comment: I've encountered the same issue as OP only it was on a Pi 1.  The only thing that allowed me to enable SSH was to plug it into a monitor and keyboard and select the option.

Answer (score 1):

First of all I am new to Raspberry Pi 3 but I can successfuly connect to my  Pi by using Putty. Secondly, I did not use any "blank ssh file" at all. All you have to do to connect via Putty is:

1. Write "ifconfig" to the terminal in Raspberry Pi.
2. There has to be eth0 section on top where you can see inet addr:"IP "address of your raspberry".
3. Open up the Putty.
4. Select "SSH".
5. Enter your IP Adress. And click open.
6. Terminal will open and it will ask "login as:". I assume you have not changed anything about your sudo, so it must be "pi". Write "pi" and enter.
7. Now it will ask you your password. Again I assume you have not changed anything and it is "raspberry". Tap enter and I hope you successfully connected to your raspberry.

Comment: How do you connect to the Pi before you get SSH enabled?  This doesn't answer OP's question.

Comment: I actually did nothing about enabling ssh in my Raspberry Pi and just did the steps above. That is why I didn't understand what does s/he mean by blank ssh file. Here is where I learned it . [Remotely Connect from Windows with Putty SSH Telnet Client](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nQo5Qhvx5nc&t=276s&list=PLGs0VKk2DiYypuwUUM2wxzcI9BJHK4Bfh&index=18)

Comment: Exactly, you have to enable it before you can use it headless, that's what the OP is asking about.

Comment: I think it was ON by default on my raspberry. However, I might as well fail to answer the question.

Comment: It used to be turned on by default, they changed a while back to be off by default for security reasons.

Answer (score 1):

Ok so I have finally figured out how to enable SSH on Raspberry Pi 3 Model B and I have written a blog post on it.

There are too many images and bullet points which I need to show here in order to tell people how to solve this problem so please refer to this blog post (I am not advertising my blog!)

Here is the link:
https://nikhilraghava.wordpress.com/2017/07/05/setting-up-the-raspberry-pi-on-headless-mode/

Comment: This is a link-only answer which should be improved to be up to the site's standards.

Comment: Edit your answer for some points, and while you're at it, a few suggestions: 1. You can copy a working wpa_supplicant.conf to the /boot directory on your microSD card and raspbian will copy it and use it to enable bringing up wireless in a headless configuration, 2. You can locate the RPi as raspberrypi.local without knowing the IP address (assuming you didn't rename it at this point.)

Answer (score 0):

You can fix this problem by enabling `ssh` connection in raspberry pi 3. First you want connect raspberry pi 3 into monitor via HDMI port. Then you can connect raspberry pi 3 into wifi network to get internet connection. After that you should install openssh server.